# CodeIgniter + PHPExcel: Error when try to create a chart

Tags: php, codeigniter, charts, phpexcel

I have to develop a program which consists of creating new Excel worksheets containing different cells. The next step would be to generate a vertical bar chart to display various data retrieved from data cells.

I'm using the "33chartcreate-column" example, given by PHPExcel, to understand how the libraty works with codeigniter framework. But when I try to create the chart by calling the setIncludeCharts method I get the error:
"Fatal error: Call to a member function cellExists() on a non-object in ***\application\third_party\PHPExcel\Calculation.php on line 3327"

```
$this->load->library('excel');
//activate worksheet number 1
$this->excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//name the worksheet
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Nombre de la hoja');

$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray(
array(
    array('',   2010,   2011,   2012),
    array('Q1',   12,   15,     21),
    array('Q2',   56,   73,     86),
    array('Q3',   52,   61,     69),
    array('Q4',   30,   32,     0),
    )
);

$dataseriesLabels = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$B$1', NULL, 1), //    2010
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$C$1', NULL, 1), //    2011
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$D$1', NULL, 1), //    2012
);

/*Set the X-Axis Labels
Datatype
Cell reference for data
Format Code
Number of datapoints in series
Data values
Data Marker*/
$xAxisTickValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'Worksheet!$A$2:$A$5', NULL, 4), //    Q1 to Q4
);

/*Set the Data values for each data series we want to plot
Datatype
Cell reference for data
Format Code
Number of datapoints in series
Data values
Data Marker*/
$dataSeriesValues = array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$B$2:$B$5', NULL, 4),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$C$2:$C$5', NULL, 4),
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('Number', 'Worksheet!$D$2:$D$5', NULL, 4),
);

//Build the dataseries
$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART,        // plotType
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,    // plotGrouping
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),            // plotOrder
    $dataseriesLabels,                               // plotLabel
    $xAxisTickValues,                                // plotCategory
    $dataSeriesValues                                // plotValues
);

/*Set additional dataseries parameters
Make it a vertical column rather than a horizontal bar graph*/
$series->setPlotDirection(PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::DIRECTION_COL);

//Set the series in the plot area
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(NULL, array($series));

//Set the chart legend
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_RIGHT, NULL,false);
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Test Column Chart');
$yAxisLabel = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Value ($k)');

//Create the chart
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',           // name
    $title,             // title
    $legend,            // legend
    $plotarea,          // plotArea
    true,               // plotVisibleOnly
    0,                  // displayBlanksAs
    NULL,               // xAxisLabel
    $yAxisLabel         // yAxisLabel
);

$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->addChart($chart);
// Save Excel 2007 file
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
<b>$objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);</b> //line 1327
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Comment: It's more important to see the calls that you're using to define the chart than the code you're using to save the file... setIncludeCharts(TRUE) simply tells PHPExcel to include the chart you've defined.

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, I have been updated the code, adding the call to define the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found my error:

```
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Nombre de la hoja');
```

I can't call `setTitle` method after I call the `setActiveSheetIndex` method.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to set a worksheet title if charts are being added to a worksheet. In 1.7.9 a fatal error is generated and in 1.8.2 the spreadsheet is output but the chart is populated with invalid values, so there appears to be some kind of internal conflict within the code that was never resolved.